# Getting breakpoint error when trying to start transfer of data from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!

@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    print("Username entered is  \(username.text)")

    let displayViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DisplayViewController") as! DisplayViewController

    displayViewController.usernameEntered = username.text

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(displayViewController, animated: true)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I'm trying to transfer this data "username" to another view controller. I have most of it working fine but there's a breakpoint error on `displayViewController.usernameEntered = username.text`

Here is the code for my other view controller:

```
import UIKit

class DisplayViewController: UIViewController {

var usernameEntered:String?

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let usernameToDisplay = usernameEntered
    {
        self.usernameLabel.text = usernameToDisplay
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Any insights as to why this is happening will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what the error u face

Comment: your `username.text` may be nil. Did you check it's value first? Try putting an optional binding there

Comment: Have you connected `usernameLabel` to the text field in your storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `username.text` should not be `nil`

& make sure that you have connected `usernameEntered` label outlet from storyboard.